# Linear algebra and percentages

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose 30% of people in England and 40% of people in Scotland detest British food. Let v1 and v2 be the number of poeople in England and Scotland. Let w1 and w2 be the number of people in England and Scotland who detest British food and do not detest British food. find a Matrix A such that A(v1,v2) = (w1, w2).

Answer (score 0):

30% (0.3) detest => 70% (0.7) not detest

$\begin{matrix} & w1 & w2 \\ v1 & 0.3 & 0.7 \\ v2 & 0.4 & 0.6 \end{matrix}$

Not sure if you're looking for this matrix though!

Answer (score 0):

Extend the pair $(v_1, v_2)$ to a basis {$(v_1,v_2),(v_3,v_4)$} for $\mathbb R^2$ , then define a map L with $L(v_1,_2)=(w_1, w_2)$ and define L(v_3,v_4) to be anything you want =$(w_3,w_4)$, so that this last is not a scalar multiple of $(w_1, w_2)$  . Then the matrix with columns $(w_1,w_2)^t, (w_3,w_2)^t$ (extending linearly) is one possible matrix.